# grails facebook logout not deleting cookie

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using the below plugin

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-facebook:0.15.3-CORE2"
```

and i have the below configuration:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='com.fito.FacebookUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.appId=<appId>
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.secret=<secret>
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.filter.type='transparent'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.redirectToReferer = true
```

when i logout facebook with

```
(<g:link uri="/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</g:link>)
```

it is not deleting the facebook cookie . Logout is working only if i logout from facebook.

Can any one please let me know if i am missing something.

I have also tried to implement logout handler but bot able to find easy way to get appId from logouthandler

Comment: you have to `revoke authorisation`, sorry have no idea how to do that in this plugin.. btw, why aren't you using the "standard" oauth plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth ?

Comment: I am using spring-security-facebook:0.15.3-CORE2 because i want to have my own authentication (user can signup and use provided by spring  security core) as well as facebook and openid login. I am not sure if this can be done with http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

You have to use client side logout, transparent filter just uses provided cookies, you cannot remove fb cookie. I mean you need to call FB.logout()(will logout from FB as well) and reload the page.